# Apache Camel Exception Generated when routing to a route

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, rest

I am pretty new to spring-boot and  apache camel.  I am trying to create an application which will ivoke a rest end point which I am hosting locally using Camel for routing.

When I run the app, I get the error : `CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange`  and `HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:8080/myservice with statusCode: 415` and `errorDescription":"Unsupported Media Type"`

**POM:**

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

**MsgRouteBuilder:**

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:firstRoute")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("GET"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .to("http://localhost:8080/myservice");
}
```

**MainApp.java:**

```java
package me.ad.myCamel;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

import me.ad.myCamel.router.MessageRouteBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableCaching
public class MeAdApp implements CommandLineRunner {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MeAdApp.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      SpringApplication.run(MeAdApp.class, args);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Starting MeAdApp...");
  }  
}
```

**MyController.java :**

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/routing")
public boolean sendMyData() {
    sendMyInfo.startRouting();
    return true;
}
```

**SendMyInfo.java :**

```java
MsgRouteBuilder routeBuilder = new MsgRouteBuilder();
CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();


public void startRouting(){

    try {
        ctx.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
        ctx.start();
        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = ctx.createProducerTemplate();
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:firstRoute", "Hello WFS");
        ctx.stop();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So, whenever I call my rest end point: `/routing`, I get the error :  `CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange`  and `HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:8080/myservice with statusCode: 415` and `errorDescription":"Unsupported Media Type, content type: null not supported"`

Can some one help me out here ?

Comment: You are mixing versions here. The **groupId** for `camel-spring-boot-starter` will be `org.apache.camel.springboot` and change the version to 3.2.0.

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak Yes . I found out that yesterday . sorry forgot to mention that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was wrong camel version . Once I started using 3.2.0 as an uniform version it all worked out in the end .